# How do you make a Nextcord bot tell a user that they have insufficient permissions?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, nextcord

How would you make a Nextcord bot send a message in chat telling a user that they have insufficient permissions when using `@application_checks`? Eg:

```
@bot.slash_command()
@application_checks.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def testperms(interaction: Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message('You can manage messages.')
```

How would you make it tell the user they **Can't** manage messages (ect) if they don't have the permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

Like a regular message command, you can check for any errors raised by your checks or slash command using the following decorator: `@testperms.error`

In this error handling function, you can check if the error raised is of type `ApplicationMissingPermissions` and then send an error message in response to the interaction.

### Code

```py
@bot.slash_command()
@application_checks.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def testperms(interaction: Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message('You can manage messages.')


@testperms.error
async def on_testperms_error(interaction: Interaction, error):
    if isinstance(error, application_checks.ApplicationMissingPermissions):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You cannot manage messages.")
    else:
        raise error
```

### Reference

[`ApplicationMissingPermissions`](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/ext/application_checks/index.html?highlight=applicationmissingpermissions#nextcord.ext.application_checks.ApplicationMissingPermissions)

[application_checks](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/ext/application_checks/index.html)

Comment: How would you make it so one event is used for all commands the user can't use due to insufficient permissions instead of one event per command that has permission checks?